# I have to activate my win8 pro whenever I connect to the internet

Tags: windows-activation

Four months ago I bought Windows8 Pro and activated it.

I have had no problems at all until a few days ago: every time I connect to the Internet a notification by the Action Center pops up  and forces me to activate Windows.

Once I click the "activate" button it is active again in no time.

Question: How did this problem appear? How to solve it?